# convert list of object to map java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, mybatis

I have pojo as below

```
Class Employee () {
 Private name;
 Private id;
}
```

this employee class is used to fetch list of objects (List) from mybatis orm.

mybatis return output as List since mybatis is not supporting Map as return type

I have to convert it to Map

I tried below one but didn't worked since it is expecting getName() and getId() methos

```
Map<String, String> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Employee:getName));
```

Please advise is there a way to achieve with stream without modifying Employee pojo.

Note : I am aware that we can achieve using ofr or for each loops.

Comment: What is `Employee:getValue` supposed to be? What do you want the value of your Map to hold?

Comment: Apologies, It is Employee::getId Map has to hold name as key and id as value.

Comment: In that case, it should be `Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName, Employee::getId)`

Comment: yes that is typo issue,

Comment: *I tried below one but didn't worked*... on what input and what was the expected output?

Comment: @Naman, according to OP *I tried below one but didn't worked since it is expecting getName() and getId() methos*

Comment: Alright @VishwaRatna, voting to close considering it was just a typo then.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there was a typo in question.

Answer (score 2):

you shoould always post well formulated question but as you are new lets just ignore that part. I am assuming here that your `name` and `ID` both are of type string.

Below code would work perfectly for you.

```
Map<String, String> map = list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Employee::getName));
```

If you want to preserve order as well, go for below mentioned.

```
Map<String, String> map = list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Employee::getName, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue,LinkedHashMap::new));
```

if it doesn't it will be great if you add what `error message` you are getting so will be able to help you in detail.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Map<Integer, String> result1=list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Employee::getName));
```

Comment: care to add an explanation?